How to post the instagram story from the desktop?
I litrally tried to post the stories from the instagram on desktop but i couldn't find the option.
Please any one help me to solve this issue.

Are you using the istekram  snap package Instagram client for Linux in Ubuntu? If not please add the details of your OS version and the name of your Instagram client app to your question or else post it as a comment.
